# Sharing TXPostgres Connection

Tags: python, postgresql, twisted

I am working with a twisted application server, and my flow con txpostgres connectio is ( my code is follow to the explanation )

1. Open connection on tac file and pass this opened connection to the factory, also tac file open different ports
2. Factory pass the connection to the Protocol on the constructor function and assigned to a Protocol attribute
3. ON protocol, based on the port, init a Class instance, and send the opened connection through the constructor

I am using a pgbouncer, however when I am noticing is that pgbouncer on mode sentence, the issue is there are many connections that are been opened instead sharing just one, I need just use one shared connection, probably I need to use something like a persistent connection or maybe a way to use the var from any file instead passing through vars, cause looks like if each var created is cloning the opened connection instead sharing the connection

Finally my question is: what will be the right why for get the behavior explained

Thanks a lot

```
path = None
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('protocols.cfg')

conn = txpostgres.Connection()
defe = conn.connect("host=localhost dbname=gctracker user=gctracker password=PASSWORD port=6432")

application = service.Application("tracker")

factories = {}

for device in config.get('protocols', 'keys').split(','):
    devicer = config.get(device, 'name')
    factories[devicer] = TrackerFactory(devicer, conn, defe)
    internet.TCPServer(int(config.get(device, 'port')), factories[devicer]).setServiceParent(application)

endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8750)
factory = AMPFactory(factories)
ampService = StreamServerEndpointService(endpoint, factory)
ampService.setServiceParent(application)



from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol

class TrackerServer(Protocol):
    """Tracker Twisted Protocol Class."""

    def __init__(self, clients, devicer, connection, deferred):
        self.clients = clients
        self.devicer = devicer
        self.connection = connection
        self.deferred = deferred
        self.decoder = None
        self.host = None
        self.peer = None
        self.state = False

    def connectionMade(self):
        """ConnectionMade Twisted event."""
        try:
            decoderModule = __import__('listener.protocols.%sDecoder' % (self.devicer, ), fromlist=['%sDecoder' % (self.devicer, )])
            decoderClass = getattr(decoderModule, '%sDecoder' % (self.devicer, ))
            self.decoder = decoderClass(self.connection, self.deferred)
            self.peer = self.transport.getPeer()
            self.host = self.transport.getHost()
            self.decoder.openConnection(self.host.host, self.host.port, self.peer.host, self.peer.port)
            print 'Connection made to', self.host, 'from', self.peer
            self.clients[self.peer.host] =  self
        except ValueError:
            print "Oops!  Connection was not started"

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        """ConnectionLost Twisted event."""
        if self.clients.has_key(self.peer.host):
            del self.clients[self.peer.host]
            self.decoder.closeConnection()
            print "Connection lost from", self.peer.host, ':', reason
        else:
            print "Connection unknown peer:", reason

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        """DataReceived Twisted event."""
        #try:
        """ how to precess here a line for a specific client"""
        response = self.decoder.processDatagram(data)
        if  response != False:
            self.sendMessage(response)
            #d = threads.deferToThread(self.factory.decoder.processDatagram(data ))
            #d.addCallback(self.sendResponse)
        #except ValueError:
        #    print "Oops!  That was no valid data.  Try again..."

    def sendMessage (self, response):
        #print 'response', response
        self.transport.write(response)

class TrackerFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self, devicer, connection, deferred):
        self.clients = {}
        self.devicer = devicer
        self.connection = connection
        self.deferred = deferred

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        proto = TrackerServer(self.clients, self.devicer, self.connection, self.deferred)
        self.connectedProtocol = proto
        return proto


class Decoder():
    """Decoder Metaclass

    Decode datagrams according device protocol
    """

    def __init__(self, connection, deferred):
        """Class Constructor"""
        self._logId = None
        self._id = None
        self._imei = None
        self._conn = connection
        self._d = deferred
        self.status = 0
        self.processes = ()
        self.connection = {
                       'ip': None,
                       'port': None,
                       'opend': None,
                       'closed': None,
                       'status': None
                         }
        self.device = None
        self.fields = {
                       'datagram': '',
                       'imei': '',
                       'date_time_process': None,
                       'latitude': 0.0,
                       'longitude': 0.0,
                       'course': 0,
                       'speed': 0,
                       'mileage': 0,
                       'gps_signal': 0,
                       'gsm_signal': 0,
                       'alarm_status': False,
                       'gps_status': False,
                       'vehicle_status': False,
                       'alarm_over_speed': False,
                       'other': '',
                  }
        self.datagram = {
                       'bytes': None,
                       'header': None,
                       'length': None,
                       'type': None,
                       'stop': None,
                       'information': None,
                     }
        self.validation = {
                       'header': None,
                       'tail': None,
                       }
        self.types = {
                       'login': None,
                       'location': None,
                       'status': None,
                       'warning': None,
                       'alarm': None,
                       'gps': None,
                       'command': None,
                   }
        self.response = ['00', '00']

    def openConnection (self, host_ip, host_port, peer_ip, peer_port):
        self.connection['host_ip'] = host_ip
        self.connection['host_port'] = host_port
        self.connection['peer_ip'] = peer_ip
        self.connection['peer_port'] = peer_port
        self.connection['status'] = True 

        self._d.addCallback(lambda _: self._conn.cursor())
        self._d.addCallback(self.useCursorOnOpen)

    def closeConnection (self):
        self._d.addCallback(lambda _: self._conn.runQuery("select gps_close_connection(%s, %s);" % (self._logId, self._id)))
        self._d.addCallback(lambda _: self._conn.close())



class PATROLURBANODecoder(Decoder):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''

    def __init__(self, connection, deferred):
        Decoder.__init__(self, connection, deferred)
        self.types['location'] = ''
        self.response = None
        self.sent = False
        self.counter = 0
```

Comment: Please read http://sscce.org/

Comment: It's not a good idea to store the database password in source code like this (it's too easy to accidentally publish it). It's better to use the Python [keyring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring) package to store the password in the system's keyring service.

Comment: @GarethRees - Or just set set the computer which will be running this as trusted in postgres's settings, so that it doesn't require a password anymore so long as the connection is from this machine.